# Calculating price per unit (msql/php)

Tags: php, mysql, calculated-columns

This may seem like a stupid question but i have a table which is populated by a SQL query. Here is the query and table:

```
select Products, Quantity, Price FROM Products ORDER BY Price ASC
```

Now this is getting stored in a table using php. How can show what the price per unit is.. i.e. Price/Quantity and display it on the table for each corresponding row?

I have not shown price per unit on the database just the total price for the quantity.. Is this a wise thing to do or should I show price per unit before hand?

Anyway... Does anyone know how I can do this In php?? I believe I might need to use the 'AS'
keyword?

Thanks.

Comment: You should have price per unit stored in your db!

Comment: @MateiMihai Thanks I guess I shall do this then.. What happens if a seller sells there product by filling in the form.. And I tell them to specify the price and quantity... Shall I before submitting the form do Price/Quantity too and insert this in a row? Any idea how I can do this please??

Comment: You should store one or the other but not both. Obviously, it makes more sense to store the unit price.

Comment: @Strawberry Yeah it does Thanks for this I shall make this modification. I have however, already had some records now I know I can use ALTER Table Colom and add a new colum in the DB... But how can I update the rows automatically? Is there any way this would be possible?

Comment: Go on. Make a stab at figuring that one out for yourself!

Answer (score 3):

```
select Products, Quantity, Price, (Price/Quantity) as PricePerUnit FROM Products ORDER BY Price ASC
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew it would be something easy and simple:( .. lol.. I can order it by PricePerUnit ASC too right?

Comment: Yes. `ORDER BY PricePerUnit ASC`

Comment: @deed02392 Thanks I think it is wise storing it in DB before hand like mentioned.

Comment: Hi, a small issue. This works however, the as you do price/quantity I get a long answer. How can I keep the priceperunit maximum 2 numbers after the decimal point?? Thanks

Comment: select Products, Quantity, Price, ROUND((Price/Quantity),2) as PricePerUnit FROM Products ORDER BY Price ASC